# Where is the current repository for Eclipse Monkey Project

Tags: eclipse-plugin

On the dash project site for installing Eclipse monkey plugin propose to use following Url
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dash/update/

But at current time it's not responding

Where can I find ready to install Eclipse Monkey plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the URL : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Monkey/Overview. 
As it is not active, it has been archived. You can get the url for the archived project also from the above link.

Otherwise you can individually download the plug-ins from the section 1.5

Comment: Unfortunately section 1.5 describes plugins for Groovy and Python languages, except of Eclipse Monkey developed for using Java Script. Development of required plugin is frozen long time ago and it is absent in official repositories.